# One person election gets to vote for the president, by Isaac Asimov

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, isaac-asimov

I read a short story, by Isaac Asimov, I believe, in which the presidential election process is so far calculated that it only takes one person to vote.

I would LOVE to know the name of this short story!!!

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short story about elections being determined by one vote](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116878/short-story-about-elections-being-determined-by-one-vote)

Comment: @ibid We only close story-ID questions as duplicate when both answers are accepted (see [meta policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance)).

Answer (score 36):

I also read this story as a kid.  Looks like it is "[Franchise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchise_(Asimov))"

> In the future, the United States has converted to an "electronic
>   democracy" where the computer Multivac selects a single person to
>   answer a number of questions. Multivac will then use the answers and
>   other data to determine what the results of an election would be,
>   avoiding the need for an actual election to be held.
>
> The story centers around Norman Muller, the man chosen as "Voter of
>   the Year" in the 2008 U.S. presidential election. Although the law
>   requires him to accept the dubious honour, he is not sure that he
>   wants the responsibility of representing the entire electorate,
>   worrying that the result will be unfavorable and he will be blamed.

Comment: You can [read the story for free](https://archive.org/details/1955-08_IF) at archive.org,